# Truck Door Lock / Unlock Problem

Tags: dodge

Let see if anybody out there can help me. I have a opening and closing problem on a Dodge Dakota. Take the key chain remote control, push the unlock door button once, opens the driver side door like it should. Push it again and it opens the other three doors. Now, if I were to push the door lock button on the remote it does the following. But only if I lock it down with the remote first. Push the unlock button once, it opens the drivers side door. Push it again to unlock the other three doors and it only unlocks the front passenger door. The two back doors remain locked and un openable. The manual lock buttons get frozen in place without the ability to open the door manually. And the only way those two rear doors return to normal operation is if they are unlocked at the front driver door panel door switch. Tried it many times, does the same thing. Tried it with a different remote, does the same thing. Like to know what someone out there thinks that has gone through a similar thing.

Comment: what year is your dakota?

Comment: B.R. Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance stack.   I will say I'm a bit confused by the details of your process. This is one submission that would really be helped by the use of list format. I would do the edit, but I don't understand what you are trying to say.  Do you have the owners manual for this vehicle? What does it say about key fob functions?   Is this a new vehicle?  If so, definitely bring it back to the dealer.

Comment: Do you have some sort of child safety feature enabled?